# Lock screen via trackpad gesture in OS X Lion

Tags: macos

I want to map one of the trackpad gestures to start the screensaver or sleep in Mac OS X Lion.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't see any options to bind custom actions to trackpad gestures but you can use [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) to get this functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I may also find some other uses for the trackpad with this tool.